# Is there an API for Bluemix API Connect Service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

On Bluemix API Connect portal there is an option of importing and exporting Swagger definitions for individual APIs. Is it possible to programatically upload a bunch of API definitions and similarly download all the API definitions for a space or organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `apic` CLI. You should start by taking a look through the [documentation][1]. Also, once you have the cli installed, be sure to use the help text (ie: `apic publish -h`).